# Snowflake case when statement not working using args

Tags: python, sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, args

I am trying to make the select statement dependent on an args variable I am passing via a python script (in this case args.type='hello').

It looks like this:

```
  case when '{{type}}' = 'hello'
  then
        SELECT
        name from table1
  else
        SELECT
        city from table2 where code='usa'
  end
```

The error I am getting:

```
syntax error unexpected 'case'.
syntax error unexpected 'else'.
syntax error unexpected ')'.
```

I also tried IFF clause but did run into same issues.

Comment: Can you post your entire python program. It is not clear how you are executing the snowflake query from python. Are you using the snowflake python connector

Answer (score 0):

If you were sending this sql to snowflake and it was failing due to a syntax error, I would expect you to get an error like "SQL compilation error: ...". Therefore I wonder if the issue isn't in your python program.

Could you share more?

Comment: more details on the error states: sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (snowflake.connector.errors.ProgrammingError) 001003 (42000): SQL compilation error:

Answer (score 0):

Where you trying to set some paramters?
The snowflake python connector supports several syntaxes:

```
format: .execute("... WHERE my_column = %s", (value,))
pyformat: .execute("... WHERE my_column = %(name)s", {"name": value})
qmark: .execute("... WHERE my_column = ?", (value,))
numeric: .execute("... WHERE my_column = :1", (value,))
```

If you are using python3 you can use something like f"  {pythonvar} ".
Could you give us more context about what you are doing?